# Issues with Dokku and browserify-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, dokku, dokku-alt

I'm running a Rails app that uses `browserify-rails`. This requires Node, but I get the following on deploy:

```
BrowserifyRails::BrowserifyError:
  Unable to run node_modules/.bin/browserify.
  Ensure you have installed it with npm.
```

My guess is that Dokku is not installing Node, but **how can I tell Dokku that this Rails app requires Node?**

I have already tried a multi-buildpack setup (use Rails and Node buildpack) but it seems to install Ruby first, causing the deploy to fail.